# pandas Xlsxwriter dynamically access rows and Insert formatting and blanks rows with formula and chart

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

**Target:** So I have a data frame in excel like attached screenshot[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ho4tL.png) and placed data in the path [enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_I3W8ghNXPvbxF5VyMjY0IttkQzOMAq-)

**Step 1:** I want to insert 4 blanks rows after each different value of the first column  ["Placement# Name"] and on first blank row wanted to write a formula on selected columns like for column C, D, F, and H "=sum{}:{}" and apply formatting like currency or percent on selected column and mark bold and  put background colour on the same row. and put headers again on the second iteration. I also want to insert a combination of column and line chart at the same row where the first iteration start dynamically

**Example attached to Step 1:** [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyHHp.png)

**Step 2:** As per step 1, it will happen till the last row.

**Step 3:** After getting done for each row add grand total based on rows for rows of Total

so the expected output is like given data at path
       [enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZpB8XOAoi218ZnoK2wSOtqYX4wcq3758)
       and screenshot [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64QDy.png)

So the column ["Placement# Name] values can be changed decrease or increase.

The thing is I'm not able to put logic here how to loop through and do the step 1 till the last row.

```
for col in range(2,3):
            #cell_location = xl_rowcol_to_cell(number_rows_placement+number_rows_adsize+17, col)
            start_range = xl_rowcol_to_cell(1, col)
            end_range = xl_rowcol_to_cell(number_rows_daily,col)
            formula = "=SUM({:s}:{:s})".format(start_range, end_range)
            if final_day_wise['Placement# Name'].eq(final_day_wise['Placement# Name'].shift()):
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly geting what issue you are facing with, as you havent presented any code. But as per my understanding you want to add 4 rows and in first empty row you want to add a formula. Right?

So for the case to add empty rows, you can user `write_blank` of xlswriter.
eg.`worksheet.write_blank(0, 0, None, format)`

For the case to write a formula, you can directly mention it as data to the row. eg.

```
worksheet.write_formula('A1', '=10*B1 + C1')
worksheet.write(1,0, '=SUM(B1 + C1)')
```

For more info you can refer [XlsxWritter Documentation](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/)

If you are looking for any other thing, please explain it with code snippet.

Comment: so the thing is the rows are dynamic, its not as static you are saying I already have gone through the documentation of xlsxwriter. if you will check the input and output file presented at path or check the screen shots, you will get to know. what I'm asking about. Thanks

Comment: can you present some code what you have done till the time, so that I can suggest edit in the same.

Comment: so see the edits am able to find a first and last row of the data frame through shape method. Now first I want to insert 4 blanks rows on data based on first column, if current row is not equal to previous row for column ["Placemen# Name] and while inserting first blank row want to right sum formula for all above rows before blank row and format the output with bold and background colour. This can achieved by loop in think. but don't know how to get its done.

Comment: I am not getting anything from your code but can you use variables to represent rows and columns? ex. initialy row=2; after entering data, each time it will increased by  1, so that it will point to next row. And in your special case row will increased by 4 and and at row-3rd position you can insert your formula.

Comment: And if you are looking for an 'insert new row' functionality in xlsxwriter, then unfortunately it is not possible in xlsxwriter.